# Select menu padding but not to move the drop arrow

Tags: html, css, select, padding

I wonder is there any way to give right padding to the selected text but not for the arrow to move.

In this html I have given right padding as 15px, it is taking padding  including the drop arrow. What I exactly need is, a bit space between arrow and the selected option (Since option text is too long it is going under the arrow now that is why I need to give some white space between arrow and the selected option)

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>An Option xvcxbxcvb cvn cvncvnb</option>
     <option>An Option xvcxbxcvb cvn </option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
    line-height: 30px;
    padding:9px 15px 9px 9px;
    width:150px
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B858P/313/)**

Comment: Perhaps you will find this useful: http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: Not really!! If you give long text then that demo is messing  up!!

Answer (score -1):

Could you not just set the `select` `width:` to `auto;`

```
select {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding:9px 15px 9px 9px;
  width:auto;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B858P/314/)**

Comment: For some reason NO. I have uniform width for all the text fields including select menu so.

Comment: If you try your fiddle you will see that there is the same issue with the arrow